# PHP preg_match to grab text in between two HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use preg_match to grab the text in between two HTML tags.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
 $sPattern = "/<li class=\"sample\">(.*?)<\/li>/s";
 $sText = "blah blah blah <li class=\"sample\">hello world!</li> blah blah blah";
 preg_match($sPattern,$sText,$aMatch);
 echo '<pre>'.print_r($aMatch).'</pre>';
```

However, when I run this code, I get the full HTML string returned:

```
<li class=\"sample\">hello world!</li>
```

Does anyone know what changes I need to make to my regular expression?

Note: I'm aware of other ways to parse data from an HTML page. For various reasons, DOMDocument and DOMXPath are not an option--I'm sticking with RegEx.

Comment: do a `strip_tags()` on result :)

Comment: Funny ;) I'm hoping I can get the regular expression to do what it should be doing.

Comment: Answered, but [obligatory mention](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the capturing group output.

```
var_dump( $aMatch[1]);
```

[Here is a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IbdrWD) showing that the regex is working fine, you're just accessing the resulting array incorrectly.

Comment: nickb is correct--turns out my re-creation of the code wasn't exactly representative of the problem. I was accessing $aMatch[0] instead of $aMatch[1]. Thanks for the help nickb--I'll accept the answer once possible in a few minutes.

Answer (score 6):

This should work how you want:

```
$sPattern = "/<li class=\"sample\">(.*?)<\/li>/s";
$sText = "blah blah blah <li class=\"sample\">hello world!</li> blah blah blah";
preg_match($sPattern,$sText,$aMatch);
echo '<pre>'.$aMatch[1].'</pre>';
```

Comment: It returns "hello world!" when I run it, which I assume is what you want?